# Handling Settings Efficiently

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have ClassA with a requirement to control some of its properties from a SettingsView. This will require creating a view and binding it to a SettingsViewModel. The one thing that I am looking forward to avoiding is *the thought of having to duplicate ClassA properties into the ViewModel*.

So I thought of creating an Abstract SettingsClass and add to it ClassA properties and then make ClassA inherit from the SettingsClass, but I found that this will be a problem since the SettingsViewModel inherits from ViewModelBase while multiple inheritance is not possible.

Is avoiding duplicate properties is really worth it in this case, and is there an efficient approach to this problem?

Comment: I don't think you'll have any noticeable runtime overhead either way. If you're concerned about that, you can no doubt set your mind at ease by testing it.

Comment: One reason that I wish C# Interface could support [default implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/641).

Comment: @JustinXL, woo that is advanced, hat off to such genetic driven in depth understanding of yours! I wonder what part would apply in this case and how this would theoretically affect the current proposed structure?

Comment: Like Protocols in Swift, you can provide default implementations for your Interface and compose it with your existing class. So you don't need change your base class at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is how ended up architecting Settings while making sure that its properties are not to be repeated:

[image]